# SocketException on SOAP call from Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, soap, azure-web-app-service

I have problem with connect to SOAP service. Everything works fine on localhost but after publish to azure (as deployment slot, but I tried new WebApp too with the same effects) I'm getting exception:

```
{
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "There was no endpoint listening at https://wyszukiwarkaregontest.stat.gov.pl/wsBIR/UslugaBIRzewnPubl.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.",
"ExceptionType": "System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at GusConnectorSimpleTest.Controllers.TryController.<Try>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\\Users\\lkischler.INSERT-AD\\Source\\Repos\\GusConnectorSimpleTest\\GusConnectorSimpleTest\\Controllers\\TryController.cs:line 19\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__1`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()",
"InnerException": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Unable to connect to the remote server",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Net.WebException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStreamAsyncResult.CompleteGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult result)",
    "InnerException": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 194.165.48.123:443",
        "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException",
        "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)"
    }
}
```

}

It's new solution on 4.7.2 with updated to the newest nuget packages. In project is only ServiceReference added by wizard with wsdl address and simple controller:

```
public class TryController : ApiController
{
    private readonly REGON.UslugaBIRzewnPublClient _client;

    public TryController()
    {
        _client = new REGON.UslugaBIRzewnPublClient();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Try()
    {
        string key = await _client.ZalogujAsync("abcde12345abcde12345"); 
        return Ok(key);
    }
}
```

Web.config is modified by ServiceReference wizard. I added only binding described by soap api documentation. ServiceModel part:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="e3" messageEncoding="Mtom">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://Wyszukiwarkaregontest.stat.gov.pl/wsBIR/UslugaBIRzewnPubl.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="e3" contract="REGON.IUslugaBIRzewnPubl" name="e3" />
</client>
```

On localhost evething it's ok, postman returns 200 with some data. Problem is after azure publish:
[image]

I have no idea what's wrong and why it doesn't work. I will be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Use a sniffer and compare Postman results with application.  Look at http headers and find differences.

Comment: Sniffing on localhost is not a problem but what about azure? Can I sniff requests sent from azure service?

Comment: Yes.  All IP seen on Ethernet cable can be sniff even if the source or destination isn't for machine.

Comment: How can I do that on Azure WebApp??

Comment: What machine is it running on?  You just need to have a PC connected on same subnet as Azure machine.

Comment: On large machines with multiple ethernet connection the sniffer when opened can select one one connection.  You would need to open multiple instances of the sniffer to capture more than one connection.